# Command for converting little endian memory addresses to hex code?

Tags: command-line, scripting, hex

I'm wondering is there's a command or utility already built within the terminal that can take a little endian memory address (for e.g. 5F4A358F) and convert it into a hex code (in this case \x8f\x35\x4a\x5f)?

Comment: A tool named `xxd` is often provided in a `vim` package. Write a script utilizing that to do your work.

Comment: @iBug Awesome tip, thanks. Started to do this in awk but I'll look at that also.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -le 'print scalar reverse unpack "h*", pack "H*", "5F4A358F"'
```

First `pack` the hex string and then unpack it with 'h', essentially effecting the endianness change.